# INSERT doesn't work when followed by SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID

Tags: mysql, sql, last-insert-id

There are a lot of questions about `LAST_INSERT_ID()`

In my case, issue is:

When `INSERT` is followed  by `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` there are no records being inserted

```
INSERT INTO sequences (state)  VALUES (0);
select LAST_INSERT_ID();
>>> 80  // nothing is added to DB
```

`INSERT` on it's own works OK

```
INSERT INTO sequences (state)  VALUES (0);
>>>
select LAST_INSERT_ID();
>>> 81 // row is inserted
```

For testing I am using SequelPro, DB is Amazon's RDS MySQL. Same issue happens when I use Python's MySQLdb module.

Ideally I want to insert row, get back ID of it for future identification and use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run one query at a time. Most SQL interfaces don't allow multiple queries.

MySQL allows a single query to be terminated by `;` but if there's any words following the `;` (except for a comment), it's be a syntax error, which will make the whole request fail. So the INSERT won't run either.

MySQL does have a connection option to allow multi-query, but it's not active by default. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html

There's really no reason to use multi-query. Just run the `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` as a separate query following the `INSERT`. As long as you use the same connection, it'll give you the right answer.

Comment: Will that create race conditions? I am running 400+ nodes in parallel, what if one node INSERT's right after the other

Comment: @aaaaaa why are you still in doubt? `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is thread safe it's on a connection base  .. The [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) says "This behavior ensures that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or transactions. " it will be okay when all nodes use the same connection or separated connections and not to forgot **race conditions free**

Comment: Yes, LAST_INSERT_ID() is scoped to your own session. It wouldn't be much use to anyone if it weren't! Besides, if it weren't thread-safe, then putting it together with the INSERT in one multi-query wouldn't help. It would still be subject to race conditions.